Is there a way to make the template background color mutable/personalized on Campaign Monitor?
I'm new at using Campaign Monitor, and I'm trying to find if it's possible to make background colors that I put on html table to be editable when I'm creating my campaign.
So the table looks like:
<table align="left" width="170" bgcolor="#7f9b47" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:170px;background-color:#7f9b47;"></table>

Is there a way to get the color to be editable while using as a campaign?

Does the 'layout' feature work for you? i.e. setup 2+ layouts with the different colours, and then you can swap between them https://www.campaignmonitor.com/create/editable-content/#layout

Yeah,  it is a good shape. The CM does not provide any way to change the background for any color at any time?
